# ZXing Could not load Type in Xamarin Forms for iOS

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, zxing

im getting an Error in my Xamarin Forms Application. This error only occurs on Android. iOS Works fine.

This is the line where the Exception is thrown.

```
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
```

This is the Exception

```
Could not load typeZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.ZXingScannerViewRenderer'
from assembly 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android, Version=2.1.47.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

StackTrance:

```
at ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init () [0x00000] in <30849edafd8e4fbb9f24af588a9bebb0>:0 
at AllergyDetector.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0002d] in /Users/alexanderrummel/Development/Projects/dotNet/AllergyDetector/Droid/MainActivity.cs:28 
at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <27c17fe440cf491ba8255bcefade6e02>:0 
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:ceddf78a-cf9a-4fee-97a9-ea86e17b2375 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

I use the following Versions

```
XamarinForms: 2.3.3.152-pre2
ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.1.47
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms 2.1.47

TargetFramework Android 5.0
MinimalAndroid Version Android 5.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick Google action it seems that this is a known issue with the Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.152-pre2 release. Have a look at the GitHub page [here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/424) although it also seems to happen with other version of Xamarin.Forms.

There also is a fix suggested by richardpike:

> I was able to fix this for myself by downloading the source code and
>   updating the xamarin forms package to the pre-release (2.3.3.152-pre2)
>
> This required 2 new override functions in ZXingScannerViewRenderer.cs,
>   and ZXingBarcodeImageViewRenderer.cs (from the
>   ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android project). All I did was make them
>   return null.
>
> This builds successfully and I was able to use the resulting dll in my
>   project without it crashing.
>
> I would make a pull request, but I've never done one before using
>   github...

If that is not something you're comfortable with I'm afraid you are stuck with waiting until they have fixed this.

Comment: totaly agree. i mark it as solved. thats not a solutions which should be used for production...